# 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column' Error With PK and FKs in Insert Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following script I'm attempting to run, but I keep getting the `NULL` error.  The primary key is `ID`, which is not included in my script.

I'm not the owner of the table, so I cannot make any changes in the Key folder.

I also need to point out that `UserID` and `EntityID` are foreign keys in the `Userpermissions` table.

How can I get this script to run successfully without any `NULL` or key constraint errors?

```
INSERT INTO userpermissions (
        UserID, 
        EntityID, 
        Applications, 
        Phone, 
        PhoneExt, 
        E_Mail, 
        UserTypeID, 
        InactiveDate, 
        ReviewDate)

VALUES( ( SELECT ID FROM Users AS UserID WHERE id = 710231),
        ( SELECT ID FROM Entity AS EntityID WHERE id = 2332448),
        '31525197392643072' ,
        'NULL'  ,   
        'NULL'  ,   
        'NULL'  ,   
         2      , 
        'NULL'  , 
        'NULL'  
       )
```

Comment: You could try not inserting NULL into columns that don't allow NULL.

Comment: `'NULL'` is a string literal for the word "NULL", it's not the null value... Remove the single quotes, simply specify `NULL` for the null value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Likely one of the two subqueries

```
( SELECT ID from Users as UserID where id = 710231), ( SELECT ID from Entity as EntityID where id = 2332448)
```

returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're trying to insert the *string* `'NULL' into the date fields, which do not accept non-date values. Remove the single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO userpermissions (
        UserID, 
        EntityID, 
        Applications, 
        Phone, 
        PhoneExt, 
        E_Mail, 
        UserTypeID, 
        InactiveDate, 
        ReviewDate)

VALUES( ( SELECT ID FROM Users AS UserID WHERE id = 710231),
        ( SELECT ID FROM Entity AS EntityID WHERE id = 2332448),
        '31525197392643072' ,
        NULL  ,   
        NULL  ,   
        NULL  ,   
        2     , 
        NULL  , 
        NULL  
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that if column values you mentioned as `'NULL'` are not allowing nulls and remove '' around `NULL`, if those columns allow NULL no need to put in ''.

> NULL is not a value. Something cannot '=' NULL

**PK column** `(id)` in your table `Userpermissions` is supposed to be an **incrementing value**.
You need to set this, or else if you have a non-nullable column, with no default value, if you provide no value it will throw error. Check this first and set auto-increment.

**To set up auto-increment in SQL Server Management Studio:**

- Open your table in `Design`
- Select your column and go to Column `Properties`
- Under `Indentity Specification`, set `(Is Identity)=Yes` and `Indentity Increment=1`